# WPF Replace value in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

Lets say i have a TextBlock thats bound to a DateTime, is there any way to replace the value 0001-01-01 00:00:00 with an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Bind to a `DateTime?` (that is, `Nullable<DateTime>`) rather than `DateTime`. Set the value to `null` when you want nothing to appear.
2. Bind to a separate property on your view model which is responsible for converting `DateTime.MinValue` to an empty `string`.
3. Bind directly to the DateTime property and use a converter to convert `DateTime.MinValue` to an empty `string`.

**Example of #1**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDateTime}"/>

public class YourViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private DateTime? _someDateTime;

    public DateTime? SomeDateTime
    {
        get { return _someDateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (_someDateTime != value)
            {
                _someDateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateTime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of #2**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDateTimeString}"/>

public class YourViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private DateTime _someDateTime;

    public DateTime SomeDateTime
    {
        get { return _someDateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (_someDateTime != value)
            {
                _someDateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateTime");
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateTimeString");
            }
        }
    }

    public string SomeDateTimeString
    {
        get { return SomeDateTime == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : SomeDateTime; }
    }
}
```

**Example of #3**

```
<!-- in resources -->
<local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="YourConverter"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDateTime, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}"/>

public class YourClass
{
    private DateTime _someDateTime;

    public DateTime SomeDateTime
    {
        get { return _someDateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (_someDateTime != value)
            {
                _someDateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateTime");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value ...)
    {
        return value == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to call OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateTimeString") in your example #2

Answer (score 1):

Use a converter to format the date

**Converter code :**

```
public class MyDateConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {    
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        if (dt == dt.MinValue)
            return "";
        else
            return dt.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {    
        string s = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        else
            return DateTime.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

**XAML :**

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyDateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources/>

...

<TextBlock Text="{Binding TheDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: and how would i use this in WPF?

Comment: Note that a ConvertBack implementation is unnecessary because you're binding to TextBlock.Text, which can only be one-way.

Comment: yes, you're right... I read (and wrote) "TextBlock", but I was actually thinking "TextBox" ;)